How to safely use SwiftUI's `CalendarView(visibleDateComponents:`?
How is it possible to safely use SwiftUI's CalendarView(visibleDateComponents:? CalendarView(visibleDateComponents: requires a binding that has been initialized, however it's not safe to initialize State from anything but a literal. Normally I would update the State in onAppear, but by that point the CalendarView would already been initialized with the wrong visibleDateComponents. Thank you
import SwiftUI
import CalendarView

@main
struct TestCalendarApp: App {
    @State var visibleComponents : DateComponents

    init() {
        let monthYear = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date())
        _visibleComponents = State(initialValue: monthYear) // this is not safe or allowed
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CalendarView(visibleDateComponents: $visibleComponents)
        }
    }
}


Are you asking how you can provide the visible components value from outside your view or from some persisted state?  For the example shown, a literal for your state would be sufficient.

Logically it doesn’t make sense to always set the calendar view to a literal month - clearly it should be set to the current month. But how can that be accomplished when state cant be set except to a literal?

DateComponents is a struct in the stack not a class in the heap so it's ok for the state property wrapper to init the initial value every time pointlessly when the View is re-init.

You can use a computed value to initialise your state to get the components from the calendar for .now
import SwiftUI
import CalendarView

@main
struct TestCalendarApp: App {
    @State var visibleComponents = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.month,.year], from: .now) 

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CalendarView(visibleDateComponents: $visibleComponents)
        }
    }
}


Doesn't this have the same problem as setting the set in init?

No, it does not

Actually there is no difference in behavior between your answer and my question except that in your's whenever the view struct is recreated visibleComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.month,.year], from: .now) is called before init. In mine it's called in init. I wrote a test for this.

Then I still don't understand your question/problem. The state is initialised with the current month and year when the view is shown. There are no errors and there is no unsafe behaviour.
